# Suggestion: Ability to move a comment to an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

reference here: [Gaps between page loading and CSOM calls](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67056/gaps-between-page-loading-and-csom-calls)

In a nutshell, he was complaining about a performance issue loading SharePoint and my response, figuring the most likely scenario was "Check your browser" but I put that in as a comment as I was taking a wild guess.  In such a scenario, should we just simply be allowed to answer the question as such?  Should we just have a tool to migrate a comment in as an answer?  Curious what's the best way to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete comments and just make a new post as answer, if op thinks it's the right answer they will accept it or you will get up votes.

Comment: Yup. You could copy your comment as a starting point, but you probably will want to expand on the original comment to make a good answer.

Comment: In this particular answer, my creative juices run out at "Check your browser, different browsers do different things." How about this, I give full permission for anyone to plagiarize my answer mentioned above if they can do a better job than 2 sentences.